# Trouble displaying JSON results of jquery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Javascript, JQuery and JSON, so I may be making many different mistakes, but I've always found the best way to learn was to jump right in.

I am working on a little pet project, mostly for practice, using an API provided on the site elophant.com. It's for tracking statistics from the popular League of Legends game. However, I cannot seem to get any jquery to work correctly. Here is the API of the resource I am trying to access: http://elophant.com/developers/docs/status.

Their example request is: "GET http://elophant.com/api/v1/status?key=< key >" The < key > field is a key they provide you once you register to the site. It returns information in JSON.

Here is what I am trying to do so far:

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.get("http://elophant.com/api/v1/status?key=MY_KEY_HERE", {callback : "?" }, "jsonp",  function(data) {
    $('#summary').text(data.result);
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** I removed the JSONP and replaced it with plain JSON, and I receive this console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://elophant.com/api/v1/status?key=MY_KEY_HERE&callback=%3F. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: There's a $.getJSON function that works with jsonp aswell.

Comment: Check the console for errors (press `F12` in your browser)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see no errors in the console. Does that mean it's successful, but I am just not accessing the data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, at a minimum, you have your parameter order wrong. The dataType must be after the callback function like this:

```
$.get("http://elophant.com/api/v1/status?key=MY_KEY_HERE", {callback : "?" },  function(data) {
    $('#summary').text(data.result);
}, "jsonp");
```

I also don't see anything in that API documentation that indicates it supports wrapping of the JSON in a JSONP callback function.  Are you sure this is available?

You can test this by verifying that the response you get is JSON wrapped in a function.  That might look something like this:

```
callback({key: "value", anotherKey: "another value"})
```

Comment: No, I do not. I was under the impression that JSONP was for external URLs and JSON was for local URLs.

Comment: @Joshua That is correct, however the issue is that the server you are calling to must support JSONP in its API, such that it will wrap the JSON in a function.

Comment: Is there a way to "force" JSONP? I get an error without the jsonp type. The API was designed to be used externally, so I have to believe there is a way to do it.

Comment: @Joshua Just because the API was designed to be used externally, does not mean it was designed to be used externally via javascript/AJAX. Honestly, most API's out there don't provide this support as most are used for server to server calls, not cross-domain browser client calls.  You should check with the API provider to see if they provide JSONP support, or you need to come up with some other way of doing this, like having a script on your server that you call with AJAX that then goes out and calls this API in a server to server fashion (perhaps with some sort of caching in between).

Comment: I will look into other methods. I suppose I just assumed javascript was the correct route. Thanks for the help!